# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'city'

Tags: python, function, class

I take the parent variables for `PrivateAd` from the inheriting function `News`, but when I run the inherited function with all parameters, I get an error.

How I run `PrivateAd` function:

```
ad = PrivateAd(content=str(input('Input Ad content:')),
               days=int(input('Input days:')),
               city=str(input('Input Ad city:')))
ad.private_ad_print()
```

The entire code.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta


class News:
    def __init__(self, content, city):
        self.content = content
        self.city = city
        self.news_date_and_time = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        if not bool(self.content):
            print("The content can't be null")
        else:
            self.content = content
        if not bool(self.city):
            print("The city can't be null")
        else:
            self.city = city

    def news_print(self):
        print(f"""News---------------
{self.content}
{self.city}, {self.news_date_and_time}""")


class PrivateAd(News):
    def __init__(self, content, city, days):
        News.__init__(self, content=content)
        News.__init__(self, city=city)
        self.days = days
        self.ad_days_duration = timedelta(days=days)  # специфический конструктор к классу рекламы
        self.ad_start_date = datetime.now()
        self.end_date = self.ad_start_date + self.ad_days_duration

    def private_ad_print(self):
        print(f"""Private Ad---------------
{self.content}
{self.city}, {self.end_date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")}""")
```

how can I run `PrivateAd` function?

Comment: Firstly, you should never call the parent initializer twice. Also, you should prefer using `super` rather than the parent class directly.

Comment: You are confusing classes and functions — or at least using the wrong terminology when referring to the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the child class, `PrivateAd`, constructor. In this class you should call `__init__` on the parnet class just once:

```py
# ...
class PrivateAd(News):
    def __init__(self, content, city, days):
        News.__init__(self, content=content, city=city)
        self.days = days
        # rest of the code
# ...
```

By editing this part, you won't have any problem with running your script.

Comment: Where have you been 2 hours ago? Thank you!!!

Comment: It would be better to use `super()` to call the base class method.